# Reference .NET Project without affecting unit test context

Tags: c#, .net

I have class library .NET project that defines a custom ASP.NET middleware. To test this properly I need to hook it up to an web application. So I have created a second project that is a minimal ASP.NET web app. I then have a 3rd project where I set up an [integration test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

[image]

My test project references both the sample API and the class library. I do this because the class library can be configured in a few different ways and so I manage that in the setup code of my tests

```cs
_factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
{
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        // ...
    });
    builder.Configure(app =>
    {
        app.UseCustomMiddleware(options.OptionA);
    });
});
```

This all works fine a lot of the time but a particular behaviour of my middleware is that it can throw an exception. When I try to test that scenario, I expect the sample API to ultimately respond with a 500 Internal Error. However, because I'm needing to reference the class library directly into my test project, the exception is thrown in the context of the unit test and results in my unit test failing instead.
[image]

Is there a way to reference my class library so that I can still configure my sample API in different ways but exceptions from it are handled by the sample API and do not affect the execution of my tests?
[image]

Comment: Do you have a [mre]?